# Definition of maximal connected subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

what is the definition of maximal connected subgraph?
Is every maximal connected graph of the form K_n (that is n nodes and between any pair of nodes there is an undirected edge)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about maximal connected subgraph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345196/question-about-maximal-connected-subgraph)

Comment: Do I get it right that a maximal connected subgraph has the property that if I add one or more edges to it it is not a subgraph of G anymore?

Comment: @sorry Adding any non-negative number of vertices and edges (but at least one in total) breaks either the property of being a subgraph of $G$ or the property of being connected

Comment: @Smylic Thank you